# Solve ODE via NDSolveValue with NIntegrate of the Undetermined Function Being one of Terms

Tags: differential-equations

I'm new here. If there is anything not appropriate pls let me know.

I am currently working on a differential equation with one of which term is a integral of the variable.

$$
\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}=cosh(G(x))+\frac{1}{C_1}\int_{0}^{1}{u(x)sinh(G(x))dx  }+C_2
$$
with the boundary condition,  $ u(x=0)=0$ and  $u'(x=1)=0$,

where $ G(x)= 2ln(\frac{1+C_3\cdot exp(-x)}{1-C_3\cdot exp(-x)})$ and
C1, C2 and C3 are system constants which could be predefined.

To show it more simply, I let $C_1=C_2=C_3=1$ in the code below,

```
G[x_] = 2 Log[(1 + Exp[-x])/(1 - Exp[-x])];
```

```
Sol = 
  NDSolveValue[ 
  { 
    u''[x] == 
       Cosh[ G[x] ] + NIntegrate[ u[x] *Sinh[ G[x] ],{x,0,1}] + 1
       ,u'[1] == 0., u[0] == 0.
  }
  , u, {x, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 10] ;
```

However, since u(x) in the integral have yet been solved, the numerical integration would fail with the error message show:

`"The integrand {} has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}"*`

Some suggested by breaking the procedure of NDSolveValue in parts with the NIntegrate inserted. However, I am not sure how to do it correctly in Mathematica.

Thanks for your kindly help, I am really appreciated it!

**EDIT 1**

Special thanks to Tugrul Temel and  Alex Trounev, who shows the singularity point at x = 0 for G[x] function.
I make a adjustment follow with Alex Trounev, show below, for making the problem solvable!
$ G(x)= 2ln(\frac{1+exp(-x)}{1-C_3\cdot exp(-x)})$
where $ C_3 = 0.99 $

Comment: You should look at the solution carefully because there may be some variables with missing numerical values.

Comment: We have singular point at `x=0`. Therefore we can't handle this problem with Mathematica without regularization.

Comment: If we take `C3<1` then there is regular solution (I have working code for this kind of problem).

Comment: @TugrulTemel Yap...That is my carelessness! Actually C3 is a system constant and it would never be 1. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for understanding of the problem even a ill C3 given.

Comment: @Yuko You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case `C3=1` we have singular solution  with $x^{-2}$ singularity at $x \rightarrow 0$. Therefore we can suggest that $C3<0$, and in this case we have regular solution of this problem. For instance, for `C3=0.99` we can get solution with using colocation method and Haar wavelets as follows

```
C3 = 0.99; G[x_] := 2 Log[(1 + Exp[-x])/(1 - C3 Exp[-x])];

Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; 
L = 1; J = 6; M = 2^J; dx = 1/2/M; xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, 2*M}]; 
  xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2*M + 1}]; 
  pp = GaussianQuadratureWeights[2*M, 0, 1]; points = pp[[All,1]]; weights = pp[[All,2]]; 
  h1[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}]; p1[x_, n_] := (1/n!)*x^n; 
h[x_, k_, m_] := Piecewise[{{1, Inequality[k/m, LessEqual, x, Less, (1 + 2*k)/(2*m)]}, 
    {-1, Inequality[(1 + 2*k)/(2*m), LessEqual, x, Less, (1 + k)/m]}}, 0]
p[x_, k_, m_, n_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < k/m}, {(-(k/m) + x)^n/n!, Inequality[k/m, LessEqual, x, 
      Less, (1 + 2*k)/(2*m)]}, {((-(k/m) + x)^n - 2*(-((1 + 2*k)/(2*m)) + x)^n)/n!, 
     (1 + 2*k)/(2*m) <= x <= (1 + k)/m}, 
    {((-(k/m) + x)^n + (-((1 + k)/m) + x)^n - 2*(-((1 + 2*k)/(2*m)) + x)^n)/n!, x > (1 + k)/m}}, 0]
f2[x_] := Sum[af[i, j]*h[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0*h1[x]; 
  f1[x_] := Sum[af[i, j]*p[x, i, 2^j, 1], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0*p1[x, 1] + f10; 
  f0[x_] := Sum[af[i, j]*p[x, i, 2^j, 2], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0*p1[x, 2] + f10*x + 
    f00; 
bc0 = {f0[0] == 0}; 
bc1 = {f1[L] == 0}; 
var = Flatten[Table[af[i, j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]; 
varM = Join[{a0, f10, f00}, var]; int = Sum[weights[[i]]*(f0[z]*Sinh[G[z]] /. z -> points[[i]]), 
    {i, Length[points]}]; 
eqf[x_] := -f2[x] + Cosh[G[x]] + int + 1; eq = Flatten[Table[eqf[x] == 0, {x, xcol}]]; 
eqM = Join[eq, bc0, bc1];
```

Note, that $f2=u'',f1=u',f0=u$, `eqf[x]` is equation we try to solve. Since this equation is linear we use

```
{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[eqM, varM]

sol = -Inverse[m].b;
```

Finally we can plot numerical solution for 128  (solid line) and for 64 (red points) colocation points to verifier how numerical solution converges with number of points increasing. List `lst64` we can prepare with the code above for `J=5`

```
lst = Table[{x, 
    f0[x] /. Table[varM[[s]] -> sol[[s]], {s, Length[sol]}]}, {x, 
    xcol}];
Show[ListLinePlot[Join[{{0, 0}}, lst], AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"C3 = ", C3}]], ListPlot[lst64, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: This is a great solution! Thanks for your effort !

Comment: @Yuko You are welcome!

Comment: (Hi Alex, you might consider upvoting the OP's since they are new and have almost no rep yet.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much! You are right, and +1 goes at Yuko's account.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an analytical solution for free c1,c2,c3.

```
G[x_] = 2 Log[(1 + c3 Exp[-x])/(1 - c3 Exp[-x])]
```

Since the integral is a number, name it nint and solve for it later. Get anylytical solution for this reduced equation. Do indefinite integration. (I don't show the lengthy intermediate results)

```
usol[c1_, c2_, c3_, nint_] = 
  u /. First@
DSolve[{u''[x] == Cosh[G[x]] + 1/c1 nint + c2, u'[1] == 0, 
 u[0] == 0}, u, x]

integrand = u[x]*Sinh[G[x]] /. u -> usol[c1, c2, c3, nint] // Simplify

mint[x_] = Integrate[integrand, x]

mmii[c1_, c2_, c3_, nint_] = 
  Limit[mint[x], x -> 1, Direction -> 1] - 
  Limit[mint[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1] // Simplify
```

The integral has to be equal the preassumed number nint.

```
nintsol[c1_, c2_, c3_] = 
  nint /. First@Solve[mmii[c1, c2, c3, nint] == nint, nint] // Simplify

Manipulate[
  Plot[usol[c1, c2, c3, nintsol[c1, c2, c3]][x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic], {{c1, 1}, -3, 3, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c2, 1}, -3, 3, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c3, .99}, -3, 3, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is very nice code (+1).

Comment: @AlexTrounev, You are welcome.

Comment: Masterpiece, still trying to understand the code, haha

Comment: So i see, you didn't understand it.